# Add to wishlist only if user is logged in , laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, redirect, request

I want items in wishlist only if user is logged in , i am implementing that using user id , like if user_id null then redirect at login page ,
i am getting user_id null in console.log but not redirecting location ,
let me know if anyone can help me in this

i am passing user_id through ajax when heart icon clicked ,

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        myFunction();
        function myFunction() {
            @if(Auth::check())
        var user_id = {{ Auth::id() }};
    @else
        var user_id = null; // or any other default value
    @endif
    console.log(user_id);
            var search = $('#search').val();
            var categoryId = $('#selectcategory').val();
            var subcat_id = $('#selectsubcat').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '{{ url('/productsCat') }}',
                data: {
                    search: search,
                         cat_id: categoryId,
                        sub_cat_id: subcat_id
                },
                success: displayProducts   
            });
          // Function to handle adding to wishlist
      function addToWishlist() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
          }
        });

        var product_id = $(this).data('productid');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/post_wishlist',
          data: {
            product_id: product_id,
            user_id: user_id
          },
          success: function(response) {
            location.reload();
          }
        });
      }

      // Bind click event to add to wishlist button
      $(document).on('click', '.addtowishlist', addToWishlist);
    }
        $('#search').keyup(myFunction);
        $('#selectsubcat').on('change', myFunction);
        $('#selectcategory').on('change', function () {
            $('#selectsubcat').val(null);
            myFunction();
        });
    });
        </script>
```

and here in my controller i am checking condition

```
 public function post_wishlist(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = $request->all();
            $pid = $data['product_id'];
            $userid = $data['user_id'];
            if ($userid == null) {
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
}
}
```

Comment: so I can put any user id and post to their wish list???

Comment: Don't do this on the client side, check on the server side if the/a user is logged in and redirect to login if not